# SwiftUI - How to change the background of a list in edit mode

Tags: list, background, swiftui, edit

I want to change the background color of my list when it is in `.editMode`. What I tried so far is the general approach to changing the `.background` of a list via the initialisation of the view the following way:

```
init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .none
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }
```

and the setting the  background color of the list with the `.background` modifier.
This is working, but once in `.editMode` the `Color(.systemsBackground)` (black) is shown instead of the my custom `Color` (
[Picture of List in editMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC93f.png)).

My code for the list is:

```
List {
            ForEach(categoryVM.selectedCategories) { category in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditCategoryColorView(category: category, editType: .edit, name: category.name, color: category.color)){
                    ZStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(category.name)")
                            Spacer()
                            Color("\(category.color)")
                                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                                .cornerRadius(6)
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(3)
            }.onDelete(perform: categoryVM.deleteCategory)
            .onMove(perform: move)
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color("DarkGrayApp") : Color.white)
            .listRow()
           
        }
        .padding(.vertical)
// to enable edit mode
            EditButton()
```

In the code `.listRow()` is an extension, so the rows fill the whole space available.

```
extension View {
    func listRow() -> some View {
        self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -1, leading: -1, bottom: -1, trailing: -1))
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))
    }
}
```

I tried changing the color in the extension as well but it did not work.

Any idea how I could change the background color once in `.editMode` as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` did the trick for me.